# Color manipulation of a 3D model dynamically in OpenGL ES

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opengl-es, 3d-model

I’m working on a demo project where I’m using OpenGL with Jetpack Compose. I’m taking reference of this [library](https://github.com/the3deer/android-3D-model-viewer) to move my 3D model in a horizontal scrollable manner which I have achieved but the next thing that I’m trying out is to change the color of a particular portion of the 3D model but it's not applying during runtime, although it's taking the initially passed color properly.

For demo purpose, I’ve 3 buttons (Orange, Cyan, Blue) on my UI. Initially, I’m setting one color which is applied successfully. Now when I select one out of any of these buttons, the color of a particular part of the 3D Model should change for which Currently I’m passing the Hash color value and converting it into the form of RGB formatted Float Array which will update diffused color property “kd” from the respective “.mtl” file but dynamically it's not changing the color even though logs of changing colors are being printed at the point where I'm updating ".mtl" file. It would be great if anyone could help me to find out the exact location where I can do changes to make the model change the color dynamically.

**MainActivity** - Here inside the surface I'm Setting assets and having 3 buttons that pass the Hex value in order to change the color of the model.

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    LoadModelFromAssets(buttonColor)
    CameraControllerUpdater(mainViewModel.changePositionX.value)
}

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
){
Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()){
Button(
            onClick ={buttonColor.value = "#FDC984"},
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Yellow)
        ){}
Button(
            onClick ={buttonColor.value = "#CBE6D2"},
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Cyan)
        ){}
Button(
            onClick ={buttonColor.value = "#77C9DE"},
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(Color.Blue)
        ){}
    }
}
```

**LoadModelFromAssets()** - Function to load assets and setting up AndroidView within it to render 3D model.

```
@Composable
private fun LoadModelFromAssets(buttonColor: MutableState<String>?) {
        val TAG: String = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
        val uri = URI(BASE_URL_SOFA_WITH_PROGRESS_BAR)
        handler = Handler(mainLooper)
    
        // Create our 3D scenario
        paramType = -1
        val rgbArraySofa = buttonColor?.value?.let{
            if (scene != null) {
                scene?.updateColor(rgbArraySofa)
            } else {
                scene = SceneLoader(this@MainActivity, uri, paramType, rgbArraySofa)
                scene?.addListener(this@MainActivity)
            }
        }
    
        if (uri == null) {
            val task: LoaderTask = DemoLoaderTask(this@MainActivity, null, scene)
            task.execute()
        }
    
        try {
            glView = ModelSurfaceView(this@MainActivity, backgroundColor, scene)
            glView?.addListener(this@MainActivity)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "!@# " + e.message, e)
        }
    
        AndroidView(
            factory ={context->
                glView?.setZOrderOnTop(true)
                glView?.holder?.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
                glView!!
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(width = 400.dp, height = 500.dp)
                .focusable(true),
            update ={
                glView?.setZOrderOnTop(true)
                glView?.holder?.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
                glView!!
                glView?.addListener(this@MainActivity)
            }
        )
    
        try {
            touchController = TouchController(this@MainActivity)
            touchController?.addListener(this@MainActivity)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(
                  this@MainActivity,
                "Error loading TouchController: ${e.message}",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
        try {
            collisionController = CollisionController(glView, scene)
            collisionController?.addListener(this@MainActivity)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this@MainActivity,
                "Error loading CollisionController: ${e.message}",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
        setupOrientationListener()
        // load model
        scene?.init()
    }
```

**SceneLoader** - Class contains init method where I’m passing user selected color along with “uri”. In my case I’m dealing with “.obj” type model so WavefrontLoaderTask is being used.

```
public void init() {
camera.setChanged(true); // force first draw
        if (uri == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (uri.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".obj") || type == 0) {
            new WavefrontLoaderTask(parent, uri, this, userSelectedObjColor).execute();
        } else if (uri.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".stl") || type == 1) {
            new STLLoaderTask(parent, uri, this).execute();
        } else if (uri.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".dae") || type == 2) {
            new ColladaLoaderTask(parent, uri, this).execute();
        } else if (uri.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".gltf") || type == 3) {
            new GltfLoaderTask(parent, uri, this).execute();
        }
    }
```

**WavefrontLoaderTask**

```
@Override
protected List<Object3DData> build() {
    float[] userColor;
    if(object3DData != null) {
        userColor = object3DData.get(0).getColor();
    } else {
        userColor = userSelectedObjColor;
    }
    final WavefrontLoader wfl = new WavefrontLoader(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, this, userColor);
    super.publishProgress("Loading model...");
    final List<Object3DData> load = wfl.load(uri);
    return load;
}
```

**WavefrontLoader** - Here I’m loading mesh data along with the user selected color,

```
final WavefrontMaterialsParser materialsParser = new WavefrontMaterialsParser();
final Materials materials = materialsParser.parse(meshData.getMaterialFile(), inputStream, userSelectedObjColor);
```

**WavefrontMaterialsParser** - Here “.mtl” file is being parsed and post filtering for the portion of the model for which i want to change the color I’m setting diffused color (Kd)

```
else if (line.startsWith("Kd ")) {
        float[] kdColor = Math3DUtils.parseFloat(line.substring(2).trim().split(" "));
        // diffuse color
        if (Objects.equals(currMaterial.getName(), "Procedural_Simple_Cloth")) {
            currMaterial.setDiffuse(userSelectedObjColor);
        } else {
            currMaterial.setDiffuse(kdColor);
        }
    }
```

Here is the portion of the “.mtl” which I’m trying to manipulate in order to change the color.

```
#Sofa
newmtl Procedural_Simple_Cloth
Kd 0.909803 0.882352 0.835294
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.450000
d 1.000000
illum2
Pr 1.000000
Pm 0.000000
Ps 0.000000
Pc 0.000000
Pcr 0.000000
aniso 0.000000
anisor 0.000000
```